# Rails: simple_form association with i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a question regarding the `simple_form gem`.

If I have two languages and use the `t('')` function from to translate text, which I have put into my `.yml` files.

When using `<%= f.association :type %>` , is it possible to let simple_form render

`<select value="database_value1">t('database_value1')</select>` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, it'll translate collections for you: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form
Association docs: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:association

***From the docs***
Simple Form also has support for translating options in collection helpers. For instance, given a User with a :gender attribute, you might want to create a select box showing translated labels that would post either male or female as value. With Simple Form you could create an input like this:

```
f.input :gender, collection: [:male, :female]
```

And Simple Form will try a lookup like this in your locale file, to find the right labels to show:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    options:
      user:
        gender:
          male: 'Male'
          female: 'Female'
```

Maybe try: `<%= f.association :type, collection: [:some, :collection, :options]%>`

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But does this also work without collection? I get my data directly from my type table : `id | name`

Comment: Would this be: en: simple_form: options: type: database_value1: "one" database_value2 :"two"

Comment: The docs say that `association` is just a wrapper around `input` so I believe your second comment is on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for showing me those association docs: I think this is the right path `f.association :company, label_method: :company_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false` . Somehow have to set label_method to `t()` function

Comment: It should look up the labels for you automatically in your translation files.

Comment: I need to do this for `label_method: t(:name)` , but I get this error `translation missing: en.name` . It seems it does not grab the object.