# Rails - Language show label not value - Localised Language Select & Language List gems with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4 and simple form and bootstrap. I am also attempting to solve this using rails localised language select gem. That attempt failed, and I then found language list gem. My next attempt was with that gem.

I am struggling to understand simple form (big time).

My current problem is that I want my show page to render the name of the language, rather than its value. Eg, I want 'English' where I'm currently displaying 'en'.

In my form I have:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <%= f.label  'What are your working languages?',   :class => 'question-project' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7"><div class="response-project">
       <%= f.input :languages, label: false do %>
        <%= f.select :languages,  options_for_select(Profile.language_list, @profile.languages),  :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 50%', class: 'response-project'} %> 
        <% end %> 
      </div></div>
    </div>
```

I have label: false on everything because I can't seem to make simple form use my CSS. Instead, it imposes ugly bold black type font on everything.  That might be a clue as to what's going wrong.

In my profile model, I have:

```
def self.language_list
    [['English', 'en'], ['French', 'fr'], ['German', 'de'], ['Spanish', 'spa']]
  end
```

My second problem is, how do I allow users to make multiple selections. I want them to click french and english if that's what they speak.

Any tips?

I tried the suggestion below as follows:

in the profile form:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <%= f.label  'What are your working languages?',   :class => 'question-project' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7"><div class="response-project">

        <%= f.input :languages, as: :select, collection: I18n.available_locales.sort %>
      </div></div>
    </div>
```

In the simple_form.yml:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    "yes": 'Yes'
    "no": 'No'
    required:
      text: 'required'
      mark: ''
      # You can uncomment the line below if you need to overwrite the whole required html.
      # When using html, text and mark won't be used.
      # html: '<abbr title="required">*</abbr>'
    error_notification:
      default_message: "Please review the problems below:"
    # Labels and hints examples
    # labels:
    #   defaults:
    #     password: 'Password'
    #   user:
    #     new:
    #       email: 'E-mail to sign in.'
    #     edit:
    #       email: 'E-mail.'
    # hints:
    #   defaults:
    #     username: 'User name to sign in.'
    #     password: 'No special characters, please.'


    options:
      profile_setting:
        languages: 
          en: English
          de: German
          th: Thai
          ru: Russian
          se: Swedish
          it: Italian
          es: Spanish
```

The output is that the choices in the select menu are:

```
development
en
production 
test
```

I change my simple_form.yml to:

```
options.profile.languages:
  en: English
  de: German
  th: Thai
  ru: Russian
  se: Swedish
  it: Italian
  es: Spanish
```

### And i get the same output as the other simple form yml arrangement.

My next attempt is to use the localised_language_select gem.  I installed it and tried to generate the locales (although its giving me an error saying Could not find generator localized_language_select:locales.  The documentation for this gem provides an example for how to use it as follows:

```
Usage example <%= localized_language_select(:user, :language, [], :include_blank => 'Please choose...') %>
```

So I adapt that to the following in my profile form:

```
 <%= f.select localised_language_select(:languages), :include_blank => 'Please choose'  %>
```

To keep consistent with the example, I also tried:

```
<%= f.select localised_language_select(:profile, :languages), :include_blank => 'Please choose'  %>
```

In each of the above cases, I get this error:

```
undefined method `localised_language_select' for #<#<Class:0x007faeea108f38>:0x007faeeb300d30>
```

I also tried:

```
<%= f.localised_language_select :languages, :include_blank => 'Please choose'  %>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `localised_language_select' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007faee35f5318>
```

---

My next attempt was to install language_list gem.

I then set this out in my form element:

```
 <%= f.collection_select :languages, options_from_collection_for_select(LanguageList::COMMONLANGUAGES, "ISO_639_1", "name") %>
```

I get this error:

```
NameError at /profiles/2/edit
uninitialized constant LanguageList::COMMONLANGUAGES
```

Comment: if you want a multi select, you cant use it as a select... make sense, right? in your I18n you need to name it "options.profile.langauges"....

Comment: and obv you need to throw in your collection of keys, which the user can choose. my ones are the locales, i'm pretty sure you don't (!) want that

Comment: what do I change? the simple_form.yml file? I swap languages for options.profile.langauges? Not sure what to do with your advice??

Comment: your yml keys are wrong....

Comment: any idea how to fix them? i copied from your post. not sure where to look for this reference

Comment: i have a model called User::Setting. You DONT have a model called Profile::Setting....  so your key is just options.profile.languages (or .profiles. )

Comment: and our collection then is just    `collection: [:en, :fr, :de, :es]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581490/rails-simple-form-association-with-i18n

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:association

Comment: I tried changing the yml (copied above). I get the same problem as the previous yml arrangement. Not sure at all what Im supposed to change in collection. I have read the rubydocs several times over. They're too full of jargon for me to understand. Thanks anyway for trying to help. Perhaps my problem is too different to the one you've solved for.

Comment: what are you talking about. do you want me to fix it for you or what? omg

Answer (score 1):

why dont u use simple form I18n ?

We do the following for a user, that can select his current langauge (i18n locale)

in View

```
=f.input :language, as: :select, collection: I18n.available_locales.sort
```

end then simple_form.yml

```
en:
  simple_form:
    options:
      user_setting:
        language: 
          en: English
          de: German
          th: Thai
          ru: Russian
          se: Swedish
          it: Italian
          es: Spanish
```

Comment: I tried this. I have copied my attempt and the output above

Comment: Thank you for making the effort to set this out and explain the rationale. I tried it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get the same error as I set out above. Even the English option in the menu renders as 'en'. Perhaps there is something else that's incompatible in my system.

Answer (score 0):

allright, second answer. let me do all your work

config/initializer/available_languages.rb

```
AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES = [:en, :de, :fr, :es, :th, :jp]
```

template

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <%= f.label  'What are your working languages?',   :class => 'question-project' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7"><div class="response-project">

        <%= f.input :languages, as: :select, collection: AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %>
      </div></div>
    </div>
```

assuming your model is called profile (not user_profile, not user::profile or whatever)

```
en:
  simple_form:
    options:
      profile:
        languages: 
          en: English
          de: German
          th: Thai
          ru: Russian
          se: Swedish
          it: Italian
          es: Spanish
```

this is defenitely working.

maybe you should have a read about yml-keys. when i say its "key.key.key" obvious in your yml its then

```
 key:
   key: 
     key:
```

and not

```
key.key.key:
```

Answer (score 0):

My working proposition is:

Create the following in config/initializer/available_languages.rb

```
AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES = {en: "English", de: "Deutsche", fr: "Français", es: "Español"}
```

Then in your form place the following code:

```
<%= f.input :default_lang, as: :select, collection: AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES.sort.map {|k,v| [v,k]}, label: "Default language" %>
```

And, tada! You should have a list like this on your screen
[image]